# Jet Grind Radio Dreamcast Not Loading

Tags: jet-set-radio

So I just bought Jet Grind Radio for dreamcast. When I try to play it gets stuck on the first loading screen and not doing anything else. I have tried turning the system upside down and on its side. This is the only game this happens with, my other dreamcast games work fine. Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just checking, but, is the disc scratched or otherwise damaged?

Comment: not in the slightest